# Why use 0.5 as the binarization threshold in the task of CNN segmentation?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

Why use 0.5 as the binarization threshold in the task of CNN segmentation?

We often perform binarization after getting the predicted probability graph, like this:

```
Pred = model(data)

Pred = pred > 0.5
```

I am confused about why it is 0.5. I have tried setting this threshold to 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, and 0.6. It turns out that 0.4 is the best, and of course different tasks produce different results.

So why do we always use 0.5 as the threshold in image segmentation?

Comment: We don't always use 0.5, but like in most supervised learning algorithms, a default threshold must be given, and it's most of the time 0.5 (that would be strange to have a default threshold to 0.4 or 0.6, like you say it'll be a parameter to optimize according to your task)

Comment: I am using 0.95 in my case so it can vary according to your problem

Comment: @HuguesGALLIER Yes, I am worried that setting it to 0.4 will be questioned why this is the value. I still can't explain this problem very well so far.

Comment: @juvianj I have also used 0.4 as the threshold, but so far I can't explain the reason for using 0.4. It’s like I just picked one and made the best, for no reason.

Comment: This question does not really fit to stackoverflow, it is a more general problem and not a programmic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threshold is task-specific.

Therefore, there is not out of the box guaranteed threshold to work best.

The idea is to iterate among different values of threshold(evidently between 0 and 1) and find the threshold which is the most suitable for your problem.

As for your uncertainty: you use a neural network in the process of segmentation; at the moment of writing this comment, researchers are still working on the 'explainability issue' of neural networks.

Nobody will give you an answer to 'why is 0.4 better than 0.5'; there can be only conjectures.